# Having trouble evaluating Oracle rowidtochar() field to SQL Server nvarchar(18) field during SSIS load

Tags: sql-server, oracle, variables, ssis, etl

Looking for some much needed guidance. My ultimate goal is to incrementally load data from Oracle source database into a SQL Server database based on OBJID column  which is case sensitive.

The current SSIS data flow task imports from an Oracle database via ADO.NET connection and loads it to a SQL Server database using a SQL query (shown below). The source Oracle data contains a unique 'OBJID' column, which originates as ROWID data type in Oracle. The SQL statement used to extract the data from Oracle uses the `ROWIDTOCHAR()` function to convert the OBJID column for SQL Server. The OBJID column is of type `NVARCHAR` (Latin1_General_CS_AS) in the SQL Server target database.

Unfortunately, I have do not have `Created_Date` or `Modified_Date` in my source data to use for incremental loading.

So far, I created a single-row SQL Task in SSIS to select the OBJID currently loaded in target db. The result set is written to a string Variable, which I wrote into the source SQL.

```
select objid 
from dbo.target
```

However, the ADO.NET source query does not seem to pick up on OBJID variable in the where statement.

```
SELECT 
    account_date, emp_id, rowidtochar(objid) as objid 
FROM 
    oracle.source
WHERE 
    rowidtochar(objid) <> CAST('"+ @[User::OBJIDSTG]+"' AS VARCHAR2 (18))
```

I also altered the SQL query by removing `CAST()` but got the same results.

Has anyone out there attempted this before? I'm thinking my problem lies in the data types but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What type is `@[User::OBJIDSTG]` variable? Have you tried to run the last query on Oracle (passing some values instead of `@[User::OBJIDSTG]`)?

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко the `@[User::OBJIDSTG] `  ssis variable is String data type. I have been able to successfully run the query against Oracle source using the `TO_DATE` function with String variables when comparing dates for load.